# hiding a p tag a checkbox resides in

Tags: jquery

how do i hide a p tag that my checkbox is sitting in?

```
<p><input type="checkbox" name="qID5[]" class="required" value="232" id="checkbox"  /> - Answered NO to question 4 </p>
```

Here is some jquery that hides the checkbox itself depending on a condition but i actually want to hide the entire p.  What do i change in the jQuery below to hide the p and everything in it rather than just the checkbox?

```
if(value == 184){
var $radios = $('input:checkbox[name=qID5[]]');
$radios.filter('[value=232]').attr('checked', true);
$radios.filter('[value=232]').show();
}else{
var $radios = $('input:checkbox[name=qID5[]]');
$radios.filter('[value=232]').attr('checked', false);
$radios.filter('[value=232]').hide();
}}
```

Comment: when do you want to hide the p tag? any button click even?

Comment: Your statements do almost the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.parent` to get the enclosing `<p>` tag. See below.

```
if(value == 184){
   var $radios = $('input:checkbox[name=qID5[]]');
   $radios.filter('[value=232]').attr('checked', true);
   $radios.filter('[value=232]').parent().show();
}else{
   var $radios = $('input:checkbox[name=qID5[]]');
   $radios.filter('[value=232]').attr('checked', false);
   $radios.filter('[value=232]').parent().hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the statement `value == 184` will evaluate to true or false, so instead of writing the same code twice and filtering it fire times, you can use the statement directly to set true/false:

```
var $radios = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="qID5[]"][value=232]');
$radios.prop('checked', (value == 184)).closest('p').toggle(value == 184);
```

Also brackets would be preferable over pseudo selectors, and `prop` would be the correct method to set the checked state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the closest('p') selector which will search for the closest p element , which in this case is the Immediate parent..

```
$(this).closest('p').hide();
```

Or

```
$radios.filter('[value=232]').closest('p').hide(); // To Hide

$radios.filter('[value=232]').closest('p').show(); // To Show
```

or

```
$radios.filter('[value=232]').parent('p').hide(); // To Hide

$radios.filter('[value=232]').parent('p').show(); // To Show
```